# currency format in laravel

Tags: laravel, currency-formatting

I am using  currency format in lots of places  in my blade files. I am using number_format to show a proper currency format. So it looks like this

```
<p>${{ number_format($row->nCashInitialBalance, 2) }}</p> // $1,123.00
<p>${{ number_format($row->nCashCalculatedBalance, 2) }}</p> // $300.50
<p>${{ number_format($row->nCashPaymentsReceived, 2) }}</p> // $2,341.15
<p>${{ number_format($row->nCardFinalBalance, 2)}}</p> // $234.10
```

if I don't use it it looks like this

```
<p>${{ $row->nCashInitialBalance }}</p> // $1123
<p>${{ $row->nCashCalculatedBalance }}</p> // $300.5
<p>${{ $row->nCashPaymentsReceived }}</p> // $2341.15
<p>${{ $row->nCardFinalBalance }}</p> // $234.1
```

Also for the input fields I am using `toFixed(2)` in lots of places.

```
#nDiscount_fixed").val() = parseFloat( $("#nDiscount_fixed").val()).toFixed(2);
```

Isn't there an easiest way to show all the variables as proper currency format?  I have used `number_format` and `toFixed(2)` almost more then 50 times now.

Comment: Try [money_format](http://php.net/money_format) !!

Comment: For anyone coming here in 2020. money_format is deprecated, don't try it :)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You could create a [custom Laravel directive](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#extending-blade). You still need to call that directive at every place you need it but comes with the benefit that if you ever want to change the code (e.g. replace number_format with something else) you only have to update that directive.

Example (taken from the docs and updated for your use case) (in your `AppServiceProvider` `boot` method):

```
Blade::directive('convert', function ($money) {
    return "<?php echo number_format($money, 2); ?>";
});
```

To use it in Blade:

```
@convert($var)
```

Comment: I guess it is shorter thàn writing  ```number_format($money, 2)``` each time. 
if I use  money_format ( https://github.com/cknow/laravel-money). would I still need to wrap the variable? ie @money(500, 'BRL') ?

Comment: Not necessarily I think, but if you do you get the benefit of only having the specific code in one place, making it easier to change it if you ever find another package for example. The included Blade directives in that package do look nice.

Comment: @jonlink actually that is not true. The function `money_format` will be deprecated in PHP7.4, not `number_format`.

Comment: @GijsdeJong whoops my mistake. Must've had a brain fart. No need to get defensive, my friend. I'll delete the comment. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Nice idea. The directive name could use some work though. No one would know what `@convert()` actually does.

Comment: Sweet. I'd add `number_format($money, 2, , ',', '.');` parameters if you want an output like $X.XXX,XX or something. Thanks

Answer (score 27):

### Update for Laravel 10.34 (Nov. 2023)

Since Laravel version 10.34.0 you can use the [Number helper](https://laravel.com/docs/helpers#method-number-currency).

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Number;
 
Number::currency(4200); // $4,200

Number::currency(4200, 'EUR'); // €4,200

Number::currency(4200, 'EUR', 'fr'); // 4.200 €
```

---

#### Original answer:

You can add a [custom Blade directive](https://laravel.com/docs/blade#extending-blade) in the `boot()` method in your `AppServiceProvider.php` file.

For example:

```
Blade::directive('money', function ($amount) {
    return "<?php echo '$' . number_format($amount, 2); ?>";
});
```

And in your Blade file, you will just have to use `@money()` like this:

```
@money(4200) // $4,200.00
```

Answer (score 10):

I would most not use a "directive"... I found it cleaner to do the same logic as an accessor on the model.

```
public function getAmountAttribute($value)
{
    return money_format('$%i', $value);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you will need to manually set `LC_MONETARY` to influence app's `app.locale` config.

Comment: `money_format` has been deprecated on PHP 7.4: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.deprecated.php

Answer (score 2):

You can create helper functions to use in Blade:

In `app/Helpers.php`:

```php
<?php

function toCurrency($value, $currency, $fractionDigits = 0)
{
    $acceptedCurencies = ["USD" => "en_US", "VND" => "vi_VN"];

    if (!in_array($currency, array_keys($acceptedCurencies)))
        return $value;

    if (!is_numeric($value))
        return $value;

    $formatter = new NumberFormatter($acceptedCurencies[$currency], NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
    $formatter->setAttribute(NumberFormatter::FRACTION_DIGITS, $fractionDigits);
    $formattedNumber = $formatter->format($value);

    return $formattedNumber;
};
```

In `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
public function boot(): void {
    require_once app_path('Helpers.php');
}
```

In Blade:

```
{{ toCurrency($item->price, "USD") }}
```

Result: `$1,000,000`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's built-in [NumberFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php). For Laravel, wrap it in a `directive` or use in an `accessor` in the model, its up to you OR it depends on the situation where you exactly need the formatting.

- This is supported in `PHP 8`
- A multi-purpose class to format different types of numbers including `currency`, amounts in decimal numbers, percent values etc.
- Its based on country/region `locale`, for example `en_US`

`OOP Style`

```
$amount = new NumberFormatter("en_US", NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $amount->formatCurrency(1123, 'USD'); // outputs $1,123.00
```

`Procedural Style`

```
$amount = numfmt_create( 'en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );;
echo numfmt_format_currency($amount, 1123, 'USD'); // outputs $1,123.00
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to format negative numbers, you'll need to do it this way:

```
Blade::directive('money', function ($amount) {
        return "<?php
            if($amount < 0) {
                $amount *= -1;
                echo '-$' . number_format($amount, 2);
            } else {
                echo '$' . number_format($amount, 2);
            }
        ?>";
 });
```

In your blade file use:

```
@money(-10)
```

If you make edits to your directive, you'll need to clear your view:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Laravel Cashier` you can use the Laravel built-in `formatAmount()` method. 
In your `boot()` method in `AppServiceProvider`

```
Blade::directive('money', function ($expression) {
    return "<?php echo laravel\Cashier\Cashier::formatAmount($expression, 'gbp'); ?>";
});
```

In your blade view
`Total: @money($proudct->price)`

> Output- Total: £100.00

Note:

- Don't forgot to importing
- Clear config (if needed) `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Check out [my money package](https://github.com/PostScripton/laravel-money) for PHP (Laravel).

In the config you can choose a number of decimal places after the decimal point and money origin (int or float):

```
'decimals' => 2,
'origin' => MoneySettings::ORIGIN_INT,
```

After that, all money objects will have 2 decimal places.
For INT origin 100$ will be as 10000 (100 * 10^2) number.

Then create an instance and display it:

```
money(10000)->toString(); // "$ 100"
money(10000, currency('RUB'))->toString(); // "100 ₽"
```

You can add easily customize displaying of each object by passing it to the `money()` helper function or you can apply it for all further objects by setting up the config file.

Answer (score -6):

Use this solution:

```
{{"$ " . number_format($data['total'], 0, ",", ".")  }}
```

Comment: [money_format is deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) as already stated in the comments.

Comment: The format is invalid. The thousand separator should be there in 4th parameter.